# Python linux script (whois error)

Tags: python, linux

I'm trying to create a python script on linux that does a 'whois' command on every connected/connecting IP Address that is parsed from the 'netstat' command.

I am get an error saying **"sh: 1: Syntax error: Unterminated quoted string"**

and the whois usage options posted below that.

Can anyone explain to me what's wrong the script? I believe it's something to do with the for loop and the way it executes the whois command I just cant seem to find a solution. Below is the script in question:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from os import system

answer = [system("netstat -alpntu46 |grep 'ESTABLISHED\|SYN_RECV' | awk '{print $5 }' |cut -d: -f1'")]

for i in answer:
    system('whois')
```

**EDIT** So my original problem is completely fixed, I'm getting no errors. However, now all the script does is list the IP Addresses and underneath that it lists the whois usage examples:

```
-h HOST, --host HOST   connect to server HOST
-p PORT, --port PORT   connect to PORT
-H                     hide legal disclaimers
      --verbose        explain what is being done
      --help           display this help and exit
      --version        output version information and exit"
```

So it seems to be running the  answer variable but not being able to run the whois command on each address.

Comment: Count the `'`s in your line of code. A quick way to double-check your code would be to copy everything between `system("`...`")` and try to run it manually in a shell.

Comment: Thank you :) You're absolutely right, I usually run everything inside the system command in an actual shell, I must have mistyped the extra apostrophe after that

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your command string (inside de `system()` command) has one `'` more than needed (at the end of the string). Here it is corrected:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from os import system

answer = [system("netstat -alpntu46 |grep 'ESTABLISHED\|SYN_RECV' | awk '{print $5 }' |cut -d: -f1")]

for i in answer:
    system('whois')
```

**EDIT** (your second question):

When you do `for i in answer` in python you are looping through all items in your answer, that is correct, however for each IP address you are looping on you are executing only a `'whois'` command, without passing any parameters. You should add the parameter to the string, as in:

```
for i in answer:
    system('whois %s' % i)
```

that is assuming the variable `i` holds the ip string.

Comment: Wow thanks, not sure how that extra apostrophe got there hah.

Answer (score 0):

Please check the edit on my first answer (posting this just so you get notified.)

Comment: Thank you so much Lucas. I seriously love this community, I've learned more on stackoverflow/stackexchange than some of my college courses lol